# custom icons in jquery mobile failing using custom theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I can not get a custom icon in a jquery mobile list to show up for the life of me.

My assumption is that this is not working because I'm using a theme roller custom theme and that I haven't implemented it correctly. I believe that I have followed the jquery mobile example to the letter. I'm simply stumped maybe someone smarter than me will help. Thanks

jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/pagesparx/9E8jr/

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>jQuery Mobile Docs - Theming Lists</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/upstairs.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #coffeeicon .ui-icon-custom {
    background-image: url("http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/34-coffee.png");
    background-position: 2px 2px;
    background-size: 90%; }
</style>

</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Divider</li>
            <li data-icon="home"><a href="#">data-icon="home"</a></li>
            <li data-icon="custom" id="coffeeicon"><a href="#">custom-icon</a></li>
            <li data-icon="alert"><a href="#">data-icon="alert"</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the CSS selector to:

```
#coffeeicon .ui-icon-custom:after
```

#### Note

You also have to alter your fiddle a little bit to make it work (in the CSS box, you don't put the `<style>` and `</style>`, just plain css-code.